# PHP Negating Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, negation

I have tried lots and lots of solutions but unfortunately, nothing works for me.
The following is my code.

```
<?php
$x = "09-27,09-28,10-01,10-02";
$y = preg_replace("/09-\w*,/", "", $x);
echo $y;
?>
```

This will output 10-01,10-02
Now, what i want is to negate it so the output would be:
09-27,09-28
but I just couldn't find how to.
Thank you very much, I need all the help I can get.
What i want is to replace the strings that is NOT equal to the pattern given.

Comment: Why don't you try this `$y = preg_replace("~,?10-\w*,?~", "", $x);` ?

Comment: i am so sorry.i got confused.i forgot to mention that the pattern will be dynamic.it will come from a <select> value which will depend on the user.thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Just match the part you want to remove.

```
$y = preg_replace("~,?10-\w*,?~", "", $x);
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lL9kG4/2)

**Explanation:**

```
,?                       ',' (optional)
10-                      '10-'
\w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times)
,?                       ',' (optional)
```

Comment: explanation stolen from your site.

Comment: what does the ~ means?

Comment: i am so sorry.i got confused.i forgot to mention that the pattern will be dynamic.it will come from a <select> value which will depend on the user.thank you very much.

Comment: did you want to remove the last two parts?

Comment: i want to remove everything that does not match the given pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
,(?=[^,]+,[^,]*$).*$
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/1

```
$re = "/,(?=[^,]+,[^,]*$).*$/";
$str = "09-27,09-28,10-01,10-02";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Good day.The $str is supposed to be dynamic as well as the $re.So if in case my $str =  "09-27,09-28,10-01,10-02,10-03" and $re = 10- it will replace all 10- not just the last 2 matches